# php code is written to output as plain text, why?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I've installed apache server and php5 on linux, but am not able to get a simple php file executed and shown in browser. What I see in browser is this:

```
<?php echo 'hello';?>
```

Why is the php code not executed?

Here is the content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have place my test php file in `/var/www/public`

Comment: What is the file extension?

Comment: This typically means that PHP is not installed or enabled on the server.

Comment: @PaulDessert The file extension is php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these:

- Is PHP installed?
- Is relevant apache module enabled (e.g. mod_php)?
- What is the file permission of PHP file? Can it be executed by the web server user?
- Is there any error message at apache or php error
  log?

Answer (score -3):

Well you have the container missing for one,, here is a conditional with the echo call back.

```
if($result) {
       echo "success";
    }
```

Comment: what container? OP is unable to run simple php script with a single echo statement